# Warning: 'dymmy' may be used uninitialised in this fuction

Tags: c++

I am writing a program for Stack class and one of my Template Functions is like this:

```
template<class T, int initialsize>
T Stack<T, initialsize>::back()
{
    if (where >= 0)
    {
        return ptr[where];
    }
    T dummy;
    return dummy;
}
```

But I am getting a warning which says:

```
|102|warning: 'dummy' may be used uninitialized in this function
```

I have initialized it as a class T, why this is happening and what can I do to fix it?

*Note that I have to do this in older version of C++, so not C++11 and up (Cannot use the return {};)

Comment: What if `T` is a type like `int`?

Comment: Initialize `dummy`??

Comment: What type is T? If it's a primitive, then it's definitely uninitialized.

Comment: Post a [MCVE] ...

Comment: You can just `return {};`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
T dummy{};
return dummy;
```

If `T` is a primitive or POD type, it will be zero-initialized. It `T` is a class with a default constructor, it will be initialized using the default constructor.

You can simplify those two lines to:

```
return {};
```

For pre-C++11 compilers, use:

```
return T();
```

Comment: Yes but I think it was my mistake when posting the question, I need to to this by not using the C++11 or up, and the extended initializer is only available for C++11 and up, is there any other way which I can achieve the same goal?

Comment: @Dan First, I think you should edit that into the question.

Answer (score 4):

Since (according to the comments) you need to do this in C++98, you can use something like:

```
T dummy = T();
return T;
```

...or just:

```
return T();
```

Note, however, that one other alternative that may seem obvious:

```
T dummy();
return dummy;
```

...will *not* work. Rather than defining a zero-initialized variable named `dummy`, this declares a fuction named `dummy` that returns a `T` (you may want to search "most vexing parse" for more about this).

Comment: In those days I once defined a template class `Initialized`, just a wrapper for an item that would be value-initialized. But as with all such clever language/library extensions -- another case is `with` -- I stopped using after a short while. And as I've heard from others that's so with most C++ programmers, they/we invent a large number of in principle reusable solutions to small problems, use each for a little while, then forget about it and just do it the hard way each time. Hm. Don't know why this is so.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Yeah, I did that once too. But yeah, haven't used it in years now...